# Tamanho máximo de solicitação excedido HttpException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Estou tentando fazer um upload de arquivos em meu sistema, porém, não consigo devido a mensagem de erro:

> HttpException (0x80004005): Tamanho máximo de solicitação excedido.

Já tentei diversas soluções e nada

A seguir o código que alterei para tentar resolver o problema:

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>
  </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Minha aplicação é C# e utiliza MVC em sua camada de apresentação.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Senhores, resolvi o problema. O primeiro trecho de código (system.web) Se repetia 3 vezes e eu estava fazendo a alteração somente em um dos trechos.